# Collapsed sidebar as default

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm new to web applications, so I don't know HTML, CSS and JS good enough to handle problems by myself yet. I followed some YT tutorial to create collapsible sidebar, but I don't know why it is collapsed as default and i can't make it opened. I think that the problem is that i don't know what exactly is going on in my code. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong and help me understand how this should work? 
HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <li>
                <a href="#selectGameSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true" class="dropdown-toggle">
                    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-gamepad"></i> Select something</a>
                <ul class="collapse list-unstyled">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Link1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Link2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Link3</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i> Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> My profile</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-question-circle"></i> FAQ</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-phone"></i> Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-sign-out-alt"></i> Logout</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- Page content -->
    <div id="page-content-wrapper">
        <!-- some code -->
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#sidebar-wrapper{
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    transition: 0.15s;
    background-color: var(--black) ;
    font-size: 1em;
}

#sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-header {
    padding: 20px;
    background: var(--black);
}

#page-content-wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 15px;
    transition: 0.15s;
    color: black;
}

#wrapper.menuDisplayed #sidebar-wrapper{
    width: 250px;
}

#wrapper.menuDisplayed #page-content-wrapper {
    padding-left: 250px;
}

.sidebar-nav{
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li{
    text-indent: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a{
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--gray);
}

.sidebar-nav ul li a {
    font-size: 0.9em;
    display: block;
    color: var(--lightGray)
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover{
    color: #fff;
    background: var(--gray);
}

.sidebar-nav ul li.active > a, a[aria-expanded="true"] {
    color: #fff;
    background: var(--deepBlue);
}
```

JS:

```
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("menuDisplayed");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'll tell you how to achieve what you want (2 methods) and then I’ll explain how your code works.

### method 1

in your first div (`#wrapper`), add the class `menuDisplayed`:

```html
<div id="wrapper" class="menuDisplayed">
```

### method 2

you can also change your CSS to do what you want and make the "menu displayed" the default style:

1. replace "menuDisplayed" with "menuHidden" throughout your code, so that it continues to make sense semantically
2. update styles for `#sidebar-wrapper` giving it a value other than 0 for width.

```css
#sidebar-wrapper{
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    transition: 0.15s;
    background-color: var(--black) ;
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

3. now change styles for `#page-content-wrapper` too, so that it leaves room for your sidebar:

```css
#page-content-wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 15px;
    padding-left: 250px; /* leaving 250px of space on the left */
    transition: 0.15s;
    color: black;
}
```

4. the next step is to make the closed sidebar have the right styles:

```css
#wrapper.menuHidden #sidebar-wrapper{
    width: 0; /* the element of id 'wrapper' and class 'menuHidden' must have width 0 */
}

#wrapper.menuHidden #page-content-wrapper {
    padding-left: unset; /* clears the attribute that gave space to the sidebar */
}
```

---

now I'll explain how your code works (before you change the sidebar behavior):

your CSS tells the browser that the element with the `sidebar-wrapper` id should have null width (so it does not appear as soon as you load the page), but it also says that the element with id `sidebar-wrapper` should be 250px wide when inside another element that has the `wrapper` id and the `menuDisplayed` class.

the magic is in your javascript: it tells the browser to toggle the `menuDisplay` class of the element with id `wrapper`, which activates the CSS style that makes your sidebar 250px wide, and so it appears. when toggled again, the `menuDisplayed` class is deleted from the element with id `wrapper` and your sidebar returns to having width equal to 0.

the `$("#menu-toggle").click` adds an event listener for the 'click' event using jQuery. when this event is fired (someone clicks in the element with the `menu-toggle` id), the callback function is executed:

```js
function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // prevents the default behavior of the element (if it is an anchor (<a></a>), it loses the ability to change pages, etc.)
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("menuDisplayed"); // toggles the class 'menuDisplayed' of the element with id 'wrapper'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the class `menuDisplayed` to the navbar (with id `#wrapper`) initially, so on page load, it will be displayed.

```
<div id="wrapper" class="menuDisplayed">
```

Answer (score 1):

you should add the class `menuDisplayed` to your `#wrapper`. then it can show by default.

```html
<div id="wrapper" class="menuDisplayed">
```

full example can be found here :http://jsfiddle.net/9ojvnutc/